# Applying the equipartition theorem to charge on multiple capacitors

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electric-circuits, capacitance, electronics, electrical-engineering

I asked this question [here on the Electronics stack exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/668545/), but it may be better suited here since the core of the question is about the application of the equipartition theorem to the charges and voltages across capacitors. I've rewritten the question to try to make the context clear.

My question comes from reading [this tutorial paper](https://picture.iczhiku.com/resource/eetop/wYiTrqPQAKtwHcbx.pdf) called "Thermal Noise in Track and Hold Circuits" by Stanford Prof. Boris Murmann. The paper is aimed at a particular engineering scenario, but a key point is the application of the equipartition theorem to greatly simplify the analysis of some common circuits. Specifically, the equipartition theorem is applied to get expressions for the average fluctuation squared charge and voltage on capacitors due to thermal fluctuations of the resistors.

The author introduces the theorem here:

> The equipartition theorem says that any energy storage element (or “degree of freedom”) in thermal equilibrium holds an average noise energy of $kT/2$.

For the case of a circuit containing a single thermal-noise generating resistor and a single capacitor connected in parallel, the paper applies the equipartition theorem in the following way to find the well-known expression for the average squared fluctuation voltage across the capacitor:
$$
\overline{\frac{1}{2}CV^2}=\frac{kT}{2}
$$
$$
\overline{V^2}=\frac{kT}{C}.
$$

Here there is only one capacitor available to store energy so the example seems pretty straightforward. However, once there are multiple capacitors which can't be combined into a single equivalent series/parallel combination (at least, not in the usual sense), the situation becomes unclear to me.

Consider the following circuit:

[image: track and hold equivalent]

Summary of the relevant circuit details: here, the brown-shaded elements are time-varying ideal independent voltage sources. They represent the small thermal noise fluctations of the three resistors. (Their associated labels in the diagram are the values of each source's mean square voltage as a function of frequency, but I believe this is irrelevant to the current discussion. The point is each source will each generate some voltage as a function of time and each voltage source is uncorrelated with the other two sources.) These will generate some voltages $v_x, v_y, v_f$ across the three linear capacitors in the figure, resulting in some charge $q_x$ at the node which all three capacitors share. $q_x$ is thus a function of all three independent sources and all three capacitor values. Then, at $t=0$, the switch labeled $\phi_{1e}$ will turn off (in the figure it is depicted as still on, so for $t<0$), isolating the node where $q_x$ is stored from any other path, thus trapping this charge. For $t>0$, the total charge on that node must remain $q_x$ since although it can move from one capacitor to the other, it has no other path.

My confusion specifically relates to the following paragraph on page 50 (PDF page 5):

> ... think about the circuit in the “frozen” state after $\phi_{1e}$ has gone low [and the switch is turned off]. The plates of the three capacitors are connected together, which means that they are **connected in parallel from an energy storage perspective.** Charges can move from one capacitor to the other, but the sum of charges, and therefore the stored noise energy, is fixed. **The equipartition theorem therefore applies to the parallel combination of the three capacitors** and using the fact that the energy on a capacitor is $\frac{Q^2}{2C}$, we can write $ \overline{\frac{1}{2}\frac{q_x^2}{C_s+C_f+C_{par}}}=\frac{kT}{2}$.

The emphasis above is mine. I don't understand what it means for these capacitors to be in parallel "from an energy storage perspective". Typically, capacitors in parallel (like any other kind of element) share both of their nodes, which is not the case here.

I could understand arguing that since the energy stored on a capacitor is $E=\frac{Q^2}{2C}$, then according to equipartition, the following should hold:

$$
\overline{\frac{1}{2}\frac{q_x^2}{C_{eq}}}=\frac{kT}{2}
$$

Where $C_{eq}$ is some equivalent capacitance depending on the circuit and must be determined. However, I can't understand the argument for why in this case $C_{eq}=C_s+C_f+C_{par}$. Is there a way to formally justify the application of the equipartition theorem to the sum of the capacitances in this case?

Comment: > *"Charges can move from one capacitor to the other, but the sum of charges, and therefore the stored noise energy, is fixed."* It seems obvious this is false. Constant sum of  charges does not mean constant stored energy in general, because stored energy is $\sum_n \frac{1}{2}\frac{Q_n^2}{C_n}$, and $C_n$'s differ. Redistributing charge between the three plates will, in general, change stored energy.

Comment: At any given time, voltages on all three capacitors may be different, so they are not "in parallel" in the standard sense. The "simple derivation" seems completely wrong, even though it may produce correct result.

Comment: Not even in the case of all $C_n$'s being the same would stored energy be fixed. That's because $\sum_n Q_n = const$ does not imply $\sum_n Q_n^2 = const$.

Comment: @JánLalinský Thanks for pointing that out. I'm really not sure what to make of the whole thing - the author is at the forefront of this subfield so I don't think they would simply fabricate something, but I can't find any further justification for this approach in the references cited within the paper.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a way to formally justify the application of the equipartition theorem to the sum of the capacitances in this case?*

I am not sure but I think that the idea of applying the equipartition theorem came after the formal analysis of the circuit was done?

The point is that the expression $\overline{q^2_{\rm x}}=kT(C_{\rm S}+C_{\rm f}+C_{\rm par})$ was derived from first principles and included the statement, *If we went ahead and solved these integrals **we would find to our surprise***, which in turn then lead to the "hand-waving" starting with the statement, *Obviously, this elegant and simple result hints that we took a cumbersome route to get here.*

The hand-waving justification that one could use the parallel capacitor formula was that *Charges can move from one capacitor to the other, but the sum of charges [$q_{\rm x}$], and therefore the stored noise energy, is fixed* and if one looks at the original circuits (Figure 4) without any resistors shown, the three capacitors are indeed all in parallel.

Comment: Yes I agree the equipartition theorem business came about as a way to arrive at the answer obtained from first-principles analysis more easily. I've seen other situations where it's applied similarly (by the same author), but I've never seen a detailed explanation for why it should be possible.